# Attribute Table fields NULL for volume calculation - confused

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, volume

I just tried a volume calculation with QGIS on a DSM. After using the zone statistics function the attributes (mean, max, min) for the corresponding polygon are all NULL. Anyone knows why that doesn´t work?

Comment: Please explain the steps you took in more detail

Comment: I loaded the DSM, draw a polygon corresponding the area I want to know the volume of, then used the zone statistic function and choosed the DSM as the rasterlyer and the polygone as the polygone layer and choosed mean, min and max for the statistics